# SharedPreferences between two apps not updated unless first app is exited and re-opened

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two apps which are sharing preferences, the problem I'm facing is if one app write some preferences and the other app reads them, them it is the old value that is fetched, unless the reading app is exited and then reopened i.e.:

If app A is running and reads a value from preferences:

```
 ...
 prefs = m_context.getSharedPreferences (name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 m_retryCount           = prefs.getInt(RETRY_COUNT, 0);
```

Lets say the value retrieved is 10.

Now if app B runs and writes to the preferences:

```
  prefs = cityidCtx.getSharedPreferences (prefsName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit ();
editor.putInt(CityIdHandsetState.RETRY_COUNT, this.m_retryCount);
 editor.commit ();
```

Lets say the value being written is 20.

Now if app A reads the preferences again after the new value of 20 has been written by app B then the value that app A obtains is still 10. But if app A is exited and then re-opened then the value it reads now will be 20.

How can this be fixed such that app A always gets the updated values.

Comment: "I have two apps which are sharing preferences" -- what makes you think that this is a good idea? "How can this be fixed such that app A always gets the updated values" -- don't have two apps which are sharing preferences.

Comment: [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) Is probably the answer

Comment: @CommonsWare. You have no idea of the background to this, so your comments in this case are not particularly helpful. One of these is just a test app which is used for testing purposes only, to change the settings and state of the app being tested, and thus obviously it will never ship. These are legacy apps written years ago which I am maintaining and certainly can't arsed to update to an alternative mechanism if shared preferences can still continue to do the task for which they were originally used when first written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong [FLAG, that flag isn't used there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY)

> Flag for use with createPackageContext(String, int): ignore any
>   security restrictions on the Context being requested, allowing it to
>   always be loaded. For use with CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE to allow code to
>   be loaded into a process even when it isn't safe to do so. Use with
>   extreme care!

You are using [Context.getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) which states

> Operating mode. Use 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation,
>   MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE to control permissions.

You just so happen to be getting lucky that they happen to have similar values. You need to use...

[Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)

---

However... What you want is actually [Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) But... it was deprecated in 23 and does NOT allow for concurrent access of data.

> This constant was deprecated in API level 23. MODE_MULTI_PROCESS does
>   not work reliably in some versions of Android, and furthermore does
>   not provide any mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications
>   across processes. Applications should not attempt to use it. Instead,
>   they should use an explicit cross-process data management approach
>   such as ContentProvider.

Therefore, you need to use a ContentProvider.

Comment: Thanks. App B is just a test app used to manipulate app A for testing purposes, thus it doesn't matter if things aren't done "properly" as the two apps being used together is only during testing. Therefore will it still be possible to get away using shared preferences in API 23+ without having to re-implement things using a CP?

Comment: @PotassiumPermanganate: `SharedPreferences` assumes that it has exclusive control over the backing XML file. It pays no attention to modifications made behind its back while the process is running, and there is nothing in the API to force `SharedPreferences` to reload from disk even if you rolled your own means of realizing that such a reload was necessary. Your choices are to either restart the process after an external change or use some IPC mechanism (e.g., `BroadcastReceiver` that you only register in your `debug` build) to tell App A to modify its own preferences.